# Repeater only rendering half its FooterTemplate into my stream

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a repeater on my page that, among other things, has a `FooterTemplate` with a `Literal` in it that I write to in my page's `LoadComplete` event.

The `FooterTemplate` is as follows:

```
<FooterTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>Total:</b>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltrBasketTotal" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>Total inc. VAT:</b>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltrBasketTotalPlusVAT" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</FooterTemplate>
```

I know my `LoadComplete` method is working fine because I get the total and total plus VAT displayed on the screen. In my `PlaceOrder` method I render the repeater's contents to a stream to include in an email:

```
Using mStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()

    Using writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(mStream)

        Using rptSummaryContentWriter As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(writer)

            rptSummary.RenderControl(rptSummaryContentWriter)

            Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(mStream)
            reader.BaseStream.Position = 0

            customerOrderMail.Body = "Dear " & Session("displayname") & ",<br /><br />Thank you for your order through MyPortal, your reference for this order is " & newQuoteID.ToString() & ". Below is a summary of your order.<br /><br /><br />" & reader.ReadToEnd()

        End Using

    End Using

End Using
```

The problem is my email comes out with everything in the table except the last row where the total plus VAT goes:

[image: No total plus VAT row]

Has anybody got any idea why?

EDIT:

Checking the source in my email client, I've found that the `<tr>` and `<td>` from the row I want are there but nothing else. It's like I'm reading from the stream too early but I thought `RenderControl` would be done after it returns control to the caller?

Comment: I think it might be css issue, use firebug to check that element if its exists or not?

Comment: Good call on checking whether the element is there, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I simply needed to flush the stream after using `RenderControl`.

```
rptSummary.RenderControl(rptSummaryContentWriter)

rptSummaryContentWriter.Flush()

Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(mStream)

    reader.BaseStream.Position = 0

    customerOrderMail.Body = "Dear " & Session("displayname") & ",<br /><br />Thank you for your order through MyPortal, your reference for this order is " & newQuoteID.ToString() & ". Below is a summary of your order.<br /><br /><br />" & reader.ReadToEnd()

End Using
```